# AWS cloudFront and oauth2 with Autorization Code callback

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cloudfront

I am hosting my reactJs app on cloudFront, Lambda is the backend.
I am integrating with 3-party oauth2 server, which supports only the authorization code grand type. I need to handle the callback with authorization code. My problem is that the callback will be directed to the cloudFront address, like this:

```
https://dicla0olcdd7.cloudfront.net/callback?code=ss540azzC7xL6nCJDWto
```

Do you think it is a safe approach? I am a bit worried that the code is send to a service out of my control. The code should never rich any place out of my app, right?
What other solutions do I have?
thx.

Comment: *"a service out of my control"* ...meaning CloudFront?

Comment: yes exactly, I mean that the authorization code will be send to cloudFront

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront has received certifications of compliance with relevant security standards for processing credit card and healthcare data.

> CloudFront is compliant with the PCI DSS and HIPAA standards.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/compliance.html

It thus stands to reason that transient authentication tokens should also be quite safe traversing that network.

Comment: thx, I assumed it too. Also the code itself without client secret key is useless

Answer (score 0):

Customer data and privacy are of utmost concern to AWS. Your concern is valid but goes against using any platform as a service.

Many enterprises, before moving to any cloud infrastructure raised similar concerns about data, security and privacy, but ultimately the SLAs and security commitments enforced by AWS, along with the long term cost benefits override any of these concerns.

The only way to resolve this concern is to host your own data center, which is probably not the way you want to go.